# Insert quotes (single and double)

Tags: symbols

how do we insert quotes 'text' and ''text'' ?

**LaTeX**

[image: image1]

**Output**

[image: image2]

why is the quotes curled in the same directions? Should it not be in and out ... like this ...

[image: image3]

I am using TeXnicCenter v2.

Comment: One can use `enquote` package.

Answer (score 0):

Quotation marks in LaTeX files begin with back ticks, ``` `` ```, and end with single quotes, `''`.

`` `flying spot' `` -> Did the trick :)